# Finding the distance of a point from many triangles in 3D space

Tags: c#, math, graphics, 3d

This article is very close to the answer I'm looking for:

[Fastest way to compute point to triangle distance in 3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2924795/fastest-way-to-compute-point-to-triangle-distance-in-3d)

It has a lot of GREAT information on the concepts of what I'm trying to do.  I have a specific question though.

Can anyone recommend a specific **c# library** for doing this type of calculation on a large collection of triangles?  In other words, I  need to find a linear algebra C# library that I can hand a matrix of points, and a matrix of the triangle's vertices and get back a vector of the indexes of the closest triangle to each point (or -1 if it is more than X distance from ANY triangle). - QUICKLY/efficiently!

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

BTW - I am currently using this .NET library for linear algebra:

Math.NET Palladium, part of the Math.NET Project
http://mathnet.opensourcedotnet.info

... and I've ported this MatLab function:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22857-distance-between-a-point-and-a-triangle-in-3d

over to C# which works PERFECTLY for a single triangle.  It gets VERY slow though when trying to run it sequentially on thousands of triangles.  This approach also seems to largely ignore the benefits of being able to do it on large sets of triangles simultaneously.

While I felt comfortable porting the CODE from MatLab to c#, I am TOTALLY unprepared to modify the actual process to operate on a collection of triangles, and then return a vector of distances rather than a scalar value.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Finding the closest triangle for each given point in space is substantially different from the problem of finding the closest point inside each triangle for a given point in space. Looks a lot like [nearest neighbor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search), with [quadtrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) a likely tool to implement this.

Comment: The problem is that I need to know the distance as well (at least SOMETHING does).  Because most of the points I check may have a "nearest neighbor" triangle, but if they're more than 1 unit away from the point - I **don't** want to include them (i.e. return null).  Do you think this is still likely to be an appropriate avenue for me?

Comment: Yes, I'd still go for quadtrees. Or rather [octrees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) since you are in 3D. The fact that you have an upper bound on the distances you're interested in makes things even easier, since it allows you to discard parts of the search tree. Then you'll end up with a very small number of possible nearest triangles, and you'll only have to compute actual distances for these.

Comment: Agreeing with MvG. Octrees would allow you to reduce the number of comparisons you'd have to make logarithmically (assuming your triangles are separated, and if not, then they are all close)